# How to write a text on image iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, graphic

In my app I'm trying to add a text on an image. I've done it using a post in stackoverflow. It's like the following.

```
+(UIImage *)addText:(UIImage *)img text:(NSString *)text1{
    int w = img.size.width;
    int h = img.size.height;
    //lon = h - lon;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, w, h, 8, 4 * w, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, w, h), img.CGImage);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1);

    char* text  = (char *)[text1 cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];// "05/05/09";
    CGContextSelectFont(context, "Arial", 18, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
    CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextFill);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 255, 255, 255, 1);


    //rotate text
    CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( -M_PI/4 ));

    CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, 4, 52, text, strlen(text));


    CGImageRef imageMasked = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageMasked];
}
```

When I'm writing a text using this code, the original image's colour is changed like the following,

**Original Image**

[image]

**Output with Text**

[image]

Can anyone explain why is this happening. and how to fix this??

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: maybe you can just programmatically insert UIlabel on UIImage if you cannot find answer to your question.

Comment: There is no reason to resort to possibly expensive core graphics code. Just put a label over it and your done.

Comment: @DBoyer There is a good reason - if the OP actually wants to create a new image with the text on it.

Comment: You can use an imageFromView method after sticking the label on. Drawing on an image is pretty heavy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: This can only be run on the main thread! So it's pretty much useless.

```
+(UIImage *)imageFromView:(UIView *)view
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0);
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

Here's a new one using Core Graphics that can be used on any thread

```
+ (UIImage *)imageFromView:(UIView *)view
{
    size_t width = view.bounds.size.width*2;
    size_t height = view.bounds.size.height*2;

    unsigned char *imageBuffer = (unsigned char *)malloc(width*height*8);
    CGColorSpaceRef colourSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef imageContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(imageBuffer, width, height, 8, width*4, colourSpace,kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);

    CGColorSpaceRelease(colourSpace);

    CGContextTranslateCTM(imageContext, 0.0, height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(imageContext, 2.0, -2.0);

    [view.layer renderInContext:imageContext];

    CGImageRef outputImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(imageContext);
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:outputImage];

    CGImageRelease(outputImage);
    CGContextRelease(imageContext);
    free(imageBuffer);

    return image;
}
```

Comment: Where is the text?

Comment: there's no text... the problem was that the views colours were being distorted when text was added, this code allowed the view to be outputted to an image, with which you can add a `UILalbel` to a `UIImageView`

Comment: Overriding draw rect on `UIImageView` I think is forbidden

Answer (score 2):

We need to create a image context and apply drawing and get final image from this context. You can try this method. Hope this help you.

```
+ (UIImage *) addText:(UIImage *)img text:(NSString *)text
{
    CGRect rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

    // create a context according to image size
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);

    // draw image
    [img drawInRect:rect];


    UIFont* font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];

    /// Make a copy of the default paragraph style
    NSMutableParagraphStyle* paragraphStyle = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
    /// Set line break mode
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
    /// Set text alignment
    paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

    NSDictionary *attributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName: font,
                                  NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle };

    CGRect textRect = CGRectMake(20, 160.0, 280.0, 44);

    /// draw text
    [text drawInRect:textRect withAttributes:attributes];

    // get as image
    UIImage * image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

Comment: Why is `rect` based on the screen size instead of the size of the original image?

Comment: Yes, you can create image context as image size.

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(img.size);

Answer (score 1):

I am using this and it works fine for me

```
- (UIImage*) drawText:(NSString*) text
         inImage:(UIImage*)  image
         atPoint:(CGPoint)   point
{

    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:FONT_BOLD size:20];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);

    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,image.size.width,image.size.height)];

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(point.x, point.y, image.size.width, image.size.height);

    [UIColorFromRGB(0x515151) set];

    [text drawInRect:CGRectIntegral(rect) withFont:font];

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

Comment: please explain this code how to implement this code development time ..let me some example include this code

Comment: Thats seems very obvious, but if you insist I will do somewhen next week.